# Appending predicted residuals and rsquared to pandas dataframe - by groups

Tags: python, pandas, regression, linear-regression

There is a question like this already but I want modifications and have tried few methods without much luck.

I have data and want to add the R squared of a regression by groups as a seperate column in the pandas dataframe. The caveat here is I only want to do the regression on values which do not have a extreme residual values within each group (ie, within 1 standard deviations or between -1 and 1 z score).

Here is the **SAMPLE** data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gp': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
               'x1': [3.17, 4.76, 4.17, 8.70, 11.45, 3.17, 4.76, 4.17, 8.70, 1.45],
               'x2': [23, 26, 73, 72, 16, 26, 73, 72, 16, 25],
               'y': [880.37, 716.20, 974.79, 322.80, 1054.25, 980.37, 816.20, 1074.79, 522.80, 1254.25]},
               index=np.arange(10, 30, 2))
```

Now the answer which was on another post is such which works for me to get residuals in the group. This was the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

regmodel = 'y ~ x1 + x2'

def groupreg(g):
    g['residual'] = sm.ols(formula=regmodel, data=g).fit().resid
    return g

df = df.groupby('gp').apply(groupreg)
print(df)
```

Now this is great because I have a column residuals which gives the residual of the linear regression within each group.

However now I want to add **another** column which is R squared, where I want to add the R squared of the regression within each group **only for the points where the residual is within +1/-1 zscore within within each group**. So the goal is to add a R-squared which is stripping out extreme outliers in the regression (this should improve the R-squared values of a normal R-squared using all the data). Any help would be appreciated.

Edit**

FYI to add just a normal R squared the function would be this:

```
def groupreg(g):
    g['residual'] = sm.ols(formula=regmodel, data=g).fit().resid
    g['rsquared'] = sm.ols(formula=regmodel, data=g).fit().rsquared
   return g
```

EDIT 2 **

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

df = pd.DataFrame({'gp': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
               'x1': [3.17, 4.76, 4.17, 8.70, 11.45, 3.17, 4.76, 4.17, 8.70, 1.45],
               'x2': [23, 26, 73, 72, 16, 26, 73, 72, 16, 25],
               'y': [880.37, 716.20, 974.79, 322.80, 1054.25, 980.37, 816.20, 1074.79, 522.80, 1254.25]},
               index=np.arange(10, 30, 2))

regmodel = 'y ~ x1 + x2'

def groupreg(g):
    g['residual'] = sm.ols(formula=regmodel, data=g).fit().resid

    return g

df = df.groupby('gp').apply(groupreg)
print(df)

df['z_score'] = df.groupby('gp')['residual'].apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean())/x.std())
```

Output:

```
    gp     x1  x2        y    residual   z_score
10   1   3.17  23   880.37  -43.579309 -0.173726
12   1   4.76  26   716.20 -174.532201 -0.695759
14   1   4.17  73   974.79  318.634921  1.270214
16   1   8.70  72   322.80 -287.710952 -1.146938
18   1  11.45  16  1054.25  187.187542  0.746209
20   2   3.17  26   980.37  -67.245089 -0.822329
22   2   4.76  73   816.20  -96.883281 -1.184770
24   2   4.17  72  1074.79  104.400010  1.276691
26   2   8.70  16   522.80   21.017543  0.257020
28   2   1.45  25  1254.25   38.710817  0.473388
```

So Here I would like another column of R squared per group whilst not using the points which have a z-score greater and less than 1 and -1 respectively (eg would not use index 14, 16, 22 and 24 in the group by r square calculation.

Answer (score 0):

First, use your full definition of `groupreg` that assigns both `resid` and `rsquared` columns:

```
def groupreg(g):
    g['residual'] = sm.ols(formula=regmodel, data=g).fit().resid
    g['rsquared'] = sm.ols(formula=regmodel, data=g).fit().rsquared
   return g
```

Then, at the very end of your current code (after creating the `z_score` column), try the following to delete the `rsquared` entries in rows where `-1 < z_score < 1`:

```
df.loc[df['z_score'].abs() < 1, 'rsquared'] = np.NaN
```

Output:

```
    gp     x1  x2        y    residual  rsquared   z_score
10   1   3.17  23   880.37  -43.579309       NaN -0.173726
12   1   4.76  26   716.20 -174.532201       NaN -0.695759
14   1   4.17  73   974.79  318.634921  0.250573  1.270214
16   1   8.70  72   322.80 -287.710952  0.250573 -1.146938
18   1  11.45  16  1054.25  187.187542       NaN  0.746209
20   2   3.17  26   980.37  -67.245089       NaN -0.822329
22   2   4.76  73   816.20  -96.883281  0.912987 -1.184770
24   2   4.17  72  1074.79  104.400010  0.912987  1.276691
26   2   8.70  16   522.80   21.017543       NaN  0.257020
28   2   1.45  25  1254.25   38.710817       NaN  0.473388
```